# Not able to ssh to a linux instance, which is on private subnet

Tags: oracle, ssh, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to ssh into the linux instance ( OCI) which is on a private subnet. To access it firstly i have created one bastion windows host . I have configured gitbash in my bastion server and then i am trying to connect to the linux instance . , getting permission denied error .

```
ssh -i private-key-file-path username@privateIPAddress
```

furthermore, i have allowed all connection from all ports in my ingress and egress rules for this private linux instance . Also i am able to connect to this linux machine from putty using the ppk file
Just wanted to know if this is the correct approach to connect to the server from gitbash

Answer (score 0):

That is the command format I use from my bash terminal and it works for me.
I just tried to login with a user other than Ubuntu on the server and it gave me permission denied also even though the user was su status. I changed it back to the user ubuntu and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you get? You can add '-v' flag to the ssh command to get complete verbose log.

If you're using same key for both Putty and through gitbash client, it might not work. Putty uses one form of private key and gitbash needs OpenSSH format of the private key.

You can convert the key between the types using PuttyGen utility.